# how to put a trigger on a directory

Tags: automation

I have a script that scans a directory and does some maintenance on the files in it. Another process creates the files in the directory (10 - 30 files per day).

The script is called via a daily cron job . What I need is to trigger the script on an event (each time a new file is created in the directory). I prefer this rather than increasing the frequency of the cron job.

How can I do that? is there a command or a program to install?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### inoticoming

> inoticoming is a daemon to watch a directory with Linux's inotify framework and trigger actions once files with specific names are placed in there.
>
> For example it can be used to wait for .changes files uploaded into a directory and call reprepro to put them into your repository.

- [Manual page of inoticoming](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/inoticoming.1.html)

### incron

> incron is an "inotify cron" system. It works like the regular cron but is driven by filesystem events instead of time events. This package provides two programs, a daemon called "incrond" (analogous to crond) and a table manipulator "incrontab" (like "crontab").
>
> incron uses the Linux Kernel inotify syscalls.
>
> like cron, each user can edit its own incron tables.

- [Manual page of incrond](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/incrond.8.html)
- [Manual page of incrontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man1/incrontab.1.html)
- [Manual page of icron.conf](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/en/man5/incron.conf.5.html)

Comment: Could you provide an example? Links to manual pages are welcome too, I could not find the one for `incron`, the `inoticoming` one is [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/inoticoming.1.html).

Comment: For incron see the manpages of incrond, incrontab and incron.conf

Comment: I've edited your answer in a way I wanted to see it. I copied it from the packages descriptions, please be so extensive in the future when naming programs :)

Answer (score 4):

Another utility worth to know is `fileschanged` ([man page here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fileschanged.1.html)), that can monitor filesystem event on selected files or directories, for example the following command

```
fileschanged -s created -t1 $PWD
```

should monitor the current directory for file creation events, writing the name of the created file on `stdout` with a 1sec timeout.

`fileschanged` can watch folders recursively (as can `iwatch` as noted in another answer), unlike `incron` and `inoticoming`.

Comment: Thanks. And this even works with mounted CIFS Windows shares.

Answer (score 4):

There is also a small program called `iwatch` - see the [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/iwatch.1.html) (this page is for Ubuntu precise (12.04), it has links to other ubuntu versions).

`iwatch` has the ability watch folders recursively (ie: subfolders too) and to send emails in response to file/directory events.

Answer (score 2):

inotify man page is located [there](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/inotify.7.html)

if you prefer python scripts, you can use [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, I'd recommend looking at [fswatch](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch) or [guard](https://github.com/guard/guard), which both work on many platforms.