# Uploading files via sftp failed. Permission denied

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, apache2

I'm trying to upload files to Ubuntu server using `sftp`. I use `put -r dir` to upload a folder with all its content. When I run the command it gives something like the following:

```
 Uploading AuthApp/ to /var/www/html/AuthApp remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/.DS_Store"): Permission denied
 Uploading of file AuthApp/.DS_Store to /var/www/html/AuthApp/.DS_Store failed!
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/.gitattributes"): Permission denied     
 Uploading of file AuthApp/.gitattributes to /var/www/html/AuthApp/.gitattributes failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/.gitignore"): Permission denied 
 Uploading of file AuthApp/.gitignore to /var/www/html/AuthApp/.gitignore failed!
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/artisan"): Permission denied
 Uploading of file AuthApp/artisan to /var/www/html/AuthApp/artisan failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/composer.json"): Permission denied 
 Uploading of file AuthApp/composer.json to /var/www/html/AuthApp/composer.json failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/composer.lock"): Permission denied
 Uploading of file AuthApp/composer.lock to /var/www/html/AuthApp/composer.lock failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/CONTRIBUTING.md"): Permission denied
 Uploading of file AuthApp/CONTRIBUTING.md to /var/www/html/AuthApp/CONTRIBUTING.md failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/phpunit.xml"): Permission denied 
 Uploading of file AuthApp/phpunit.xml to /var/www/html/AuthApp/phpunit.xml failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/readme.md"): Permission denied 
 Uploading of file AuthApp/readme.md to /var/www/html/AuthApp/readme.md failed! 
 remote open("/var/www/html/AuthApp/server.php"): Permission denied
 Uploading of file AuthApp/server.php to /var/www/html/AuthApp/server.php failed!
 Couldn't setstat on "/var/www/html/AuthApp": Permission denied
```

I tried to change permissions, add user and apache to the group but nothing works. What else am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The better method would be for your program to upload to a user owned directory on the server (aka /home/$USER/upload/ and install a cron job in /etc/crontab on the server that copies the files over as the user apache is set to (likely www-data or apache2) into /var/www/html/ -after- making a timestamped backup of the files it is going to overwrite.

- it would solve your problem
- it would prevent data loss in case your copy does something nasty.
- no need to mess with the website settings and /var/www/html/

---

A directory watcher (see [how to put a trigger on a directory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43846/how-to-put-a-trigger-on-a-directory) ) can do this real-time.

Comment: Is this the way as for the cron job? sorry I might got off topic:    `5 *        * * *  user   mv /Uploads/dir    /var/www/html/dir`  I'm scheduling it to run every 5 minutes

Comment: Indeed that would be "5 past every hour". I would use a script though so you can create some sort of procedure. Or even forget about cron and use a directory watcher (that would make the copy real time ;) )

Answer (score 0):

The tag `sudo` runs everything as root, which you need to do to run this so instead of `sftp -r dir` do `sudo sftp -r dir` then enter your password. **Note that you will need root access to do this** If this works, please check it and vote it up, so other people can find this if they need it.

Comment: Doesn't work. What you are suggesting gives permissions to the local device not the server. Thanks anyway

Comment: @onlyforthis Oh if this is server programming, cd to your server file then do that command

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem while publishing my application from JetBrains Rider on Ubuntu server via SFTP. As there is no way to use `sudo` in this case, the easy solution was to set publish folder ownership for user, specified in ssh connection for SFTP.

`sudo chown -R username:username /your-destination-path`

Or, if you are already logged in under this user on server:

`sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /your-destination-path`